# Proof of dot product = 0 (orthogonality?)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, formal-proofs

Let $x_1,x_2$ be in $\mathbb{R}^n$
How can I prove that if $$\|x_1 + x_2\|^2 = \|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2$$

then the dot product of the vectors; $x_1\cdot x_2 = 0$.

Comment: Do you know $|a|^2=a\dot{} a$?

Comment: A friendly reminder, equations will be easier to read if you learn to type using [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site.  Using ASCII can cause difficulties to readability for many users.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $\lVert \vec v \rVert^2 = \vec v \cdot \vec v$ for all $\vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n$; apply this to the three vectors $\vec x_1$, $\vec x_2$ and $\vec x_1+\vec x_2$.

Comment: Okay. From here I foil out squaring the sum of the two vectors, make it equal to the sum of the lengths (which become dot products) and show how 2*  (x1⋅x2) must be = 0